# Office Mac - Open WebDAV URL as a command line paramater

Tags: ms-office, webdav

On Windows (and even with OpenOffice), you simply do something like:

```
WINWORD.EXE http://www.webdavserver.com/some/file.docx
```

and Word will open it off the server and allow you to edit it.

On Mac running

```
open "/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Word" http://www.webdavserver.com/some/file.docx
```

just opens a blank page. Opening a local file on the command line works fine.

Opening the webdav URL from the File->Open URL method works fine too.
Does anyone know of ANY sort of API or scripting solution to do this? Right now, I'm having to mount a folder (via mount_webdav in OSX) then pass the locally mounted file to Word, which works but is clunky as hell.

Comment: I highly doubt you run Excel.EXE on a Mac, what command do you run in the terminal?

Comment: I doubt you use excel.exe to open a docx file even on Windows

Comment: Sorry, WINWORD.exe. I run open /Applications/Office.../Contents/MacOS/Microsoft/ Word http://address.com/file.docx

Comment: Assuming your comment indeed is the way you try to access the WebDAV file, it might be a problem with the way you use `open`. Did you try `open -a "/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Word.app" http://www.webdavserver.com/some/file.docx`?

Comment: Hi, I have tried that. No luck.